# Is it possible to apply .m3u in Safari loaded as data URL

Tags: ios, html, google-chrome, audio

So basically I have a snippet which I mean to load a .m3u playlist into the `audio` element. The playlist is encoded as base64, loaded with data URI. However, it does not work.

```html
<audio autostart="true" loop="false">
    <source type="audio/mpegURL"
            src="data:text/plain;base64,aHR0cDovL3ZpZXRjaHJpc3RpYW4uY29tL2F1L3RjLzAwMS5tcDMNCmh0dHA6Ly92aWV0Y2hyaXN0aWFuLmNvbS9hdS90Yy8wMDIubXAz">
</audio>
```

However, loading the same playlist with the traditional URL `/playlist.m3u` works in iOS. It does not work in Chrome, which is fine by me now.

```html
<audio autostart="true" loop="false">
    <source type="audio/mpegURL"
            src="/playlist.m3u">
</audio>
```

**The content of playlist.m3u**:

```
http://vietchristian.com/au/tc/001.mp3
http://vietchristian.com/au/tc/002.mp3
```

The questions are:

- Is it possible to apply .m3u in Safari loaded as data URL
- Bonus: How can I achieve this in Chrome also?

Comment: http://devblog.lastrose.com/html5-audio-video-playlist/

Comment: Thank you but I tried. BTW, this what I've been able to build so far http://thanhcatinlanh.khanhhua.com - which is playlist-capable via JS.

The problem with using JS to change audio.src with onended event is that --- tada, when the iPad screen goes black, your music stops. I have tried the .m3u approach, music continues to play in background, songs are played in sequence as well. ;)

The objective is to generate .m3u on the fly so that songs can be played in background - and the constraint is NO HTTP SERVER please!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the MIME type of the data URL:

> `src="data:text/plain;base64,aHR0cDovL3ZpZXRjaHJp....`

It should be `data:application/x-mpegurl;base64,aHR...`, but I have also noticed that on Apple devices the type needs to be another, resulting in `data:application/vnd.apple.mpegurl;base64,aHR...`